# Migrate from XALAN to SAXON library in JDK 11

Tags: xml, xslt, java-11, saxon

I am currently using JDK -11 and a library called xalan.
I am aiming to remove xalan and use saxon as a replacement.
Can anyone please help with the implementation?

I went through the documentation but felt it was hard to interpret.
So any help or insights would be appreciated
Thank you.

```
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerException;

import org.apache.xpath.XPathAPI;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws TransformerException {

    }

    // TODO Refactor to work with saxon
    NodeList extractNodeList(Element ele) throws TransformerException {
        return XPathAPI.selectNodeList(ele, "//Products");
    }

}


**pom.xml**

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>TESTsingle</groupId>
    <artifactId>single</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>


    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.saxon</groupId>
            <artifactId>Saxon-HE</artifactId>
            <version>11.4</version>

            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
                    <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/xalan/xalan -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>xalan</groupId>
            <artifactId>xalan</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.2</version>


            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
                    <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>

</project>
```

Comment: Off the top of my head, if you want to use XSLT with the JAXP `TransformerFactory`/`Transformer`, it should suffice if you remove the dependency on Xalan and add the one of Saxon. If you want use XPath I would suggest to study the `s9api`, wrap your DOM document or node with a Saxon `DocumentBuilder`, then use the `XPathCompiler` created from a `Processor`, all in `net.sf.saxon.s9api`.

Comment: Hi @MartinHonnen , Thanks for the advice. Can you suggest some website or youtube channel from where I can read about net.sf.saxon.s9api.

Comment: The Saxon documentation with https://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation11/xpath-api/s9api-xpath.html and https://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation11/javadoc/net/sf/saxon/s9api/package-summary.html, together with samples they have in their resources download on Sourceforge and their Saxonica.com website should be what you need to read.

Comment: And of course the more general decision is whether you need to use DOM nodes to run XPath against because your existing code depends on it or whether it doesn't matter as the input XML is in files or generally JAXP Sources and you can just switch to Saxon's own XDM/NodeInfo representation for doing XPath without depending on the overhead of doing XPath against DOM.

Comment: https://saxonica.plan.io/projects/saxonmirrorhe/repository/he/revisions/he_mirror_saxon_11_4/entry/src/samples/java/he/S9APIExamples.java#L932 is the online version of the sample you can also find in the resources you can download from https://www.saxonica.com/download/download_page.xml#resources

Answer (score 0):

You have to make a decision whether to make minimal changes to your application, in which case it might involve nothing more than changing a single line of code that selects the TransformerFactory class, or whether to change your application to take advantage of the many things Saxon can offer beyond what you're doing in Xalan. So it comes down to understanding you project requirements, and in particular, what benefits you are looking for in making the transition.

I would quite strongly suggest that if at all possible, you wean yourself off DOM at the same time. But that depends on how deeply embedded it is in your code. Saxon will work with the DOM, lots of people do it, but it's not an ideal combination, and using Saxon's native tree model can be 5 to 10 times faster.

The other thing I tend to advise people is to make sure you have a good regression testing suite before you embark on a transition like this. It makes all the difference to the cost of a conversion project and the correctness of the result.

Comment: can we do this without using any3rd party libraries?  
    ```NodeList extractNodeList(Element ele) throws TransformerException {
        return XPathAPI.selectNodeList(ele, "//Products");
    }```

Comment: Please don't ask supplementary questions as comments on an answer - start a thread. (There are good reasons for this: one is that comments have to be short, which makes it very hard to write the question in a way that people will understand what you're getting at.)